# Creating new column with a custom function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` that looks like this

```
Name    Total
a       400
b       120
c       500
d       512
e       250
```

i have a function which takes 2 values and return me a value after some customisation, i want to create a `column` for each `Name` like below

```
Name    Total   a   b   c   d   e
a       400                 
b       120                 
c       500                 
d       512                 
e       250
```

and apply that `function` with inputs as values in `total` column corresponding to `name` column like `a,a` , `a,b` , `a,c` , `a,d`, `a,e` and correspondingly fill the values under that `column`. For example, in `column a`  for `Name a` i need to send `400` and `400` as value to that function and i get the return value and i need to fill that in `column a`. For `column b Name a` i need to send `400` and `120` as the values to that function and get the value and fill in `column b` and so on. Is there a smart `pandas` way of achieving it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the expected output, but are the following results correct?

```
df1 = df.set_index('name').stack().unstack(level=0)
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
df.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
    name    Total   a   b   c   d   e
0   a   400 400.0   120.0   500.0   512.0   250.0
1   b   120 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   c   500 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   d   512 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   e   250 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

user function:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df['name'].to_list())

def get_transform(x):
    df1.iat[0,x.name] = x[1]

df.apply(get_transform, axis=1)
df = df.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df

name    Total   a   b   c   d   e
0   a   400 400 120 500 512 250
1   b   120 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   c   500 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   d   512 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   e   250 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: how do we apply a function

Comment: The functionalizations I can deal with include the following
Create a data frame for horizontal expansion, expand it horizontally by a function and finally join it to the original data frame.